# Display Static block list in drop down in create product page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, static-block, cms-block

I want to display the static block list in magento admin product creation page.
I referred this link http://www.milessebesta.com/web-design/magento-use-custom-product-attributes-to-add-cms-static-block-to-product-page/
But it shows manual entry of static block names in custom options.
I want to show the static block option list dropdown as dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [find here](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2012/11/product-attribute-with-custom-options.html) and explanation of how you can add a product attribute with a custom source model.
The idea is to add a simple attribute like any others (via an install script) and fill in the field `source_model` with the alias of a model.
This way, when the options are retrieved, the method `getAllOptions` from the source model class is called. And that method can contain anything.

In your case, you just need to change in the example I linked the method `getAllOptions` and make it look like this:

```
public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = false)
{
    if (is_null($this->_options)){
        $this->_options = array();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $block) {
            $this->_options[] = array('label'=> $block->getTitle(), value => $block->getId());
        }
    }
    $options = $this->_options;
    if ($withEmpty) {
        array_unshift($options, array('value'=>'', 'label'=>''));
    }
    return $options;
}
```

Comment: After implementing the module, If we add a new static block, will that be displayed along with the drop down list?? @marius

Comment: @vinothavn. Yep. it should

Comment: Thats great. Tanq